# use gorm and GORM LOG sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: go-gorm

GORM LOG sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1

my code is

```
func GetPipelineConfigKey(riskConfigKey string) string{
    var PipelineConfigKey string
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT context_name FROM hawk_context_name WHERE id = (SELECT service_line_id FROM risk_predict_config_key WHERE config_key = '%s');", riskConfigKey)
    contextDb.Exec(sql, &PipelineConfigKey)
    return PipelineConfigKey
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exec` has the following signature

```
func (s *DB) Exec(sql string, values ...interface{}) *DB {
```

values is a varargs parameter here, for each variable you pass to Exec, there should be a `?` in your sql query. You pass 1 argument but query don't expect any argument(no `?`). Thats why you get following error.

```
sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

Maybe you want to save the result in `PipelineConfigKey`. Use this way for that

Create a result struct

```
type Result struct {
    Name string
}
```

And scan result

```
db.Raw(sql).Scan(&result)
```

**Full Code:**

```
type Result struct {
        Name string
}

func GetPipelineConfigKey(riskConfigKey string) string{
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT context_name FROM hawk_context_name WHERE id = (SELECT service_line_id FROM risk_predict_config_key WHERE config_key = '%s');", riskConfigKey)
    db.Raw(sql).Scan(&result)
    return result.Name
}
```